# java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.get() throw StackOverflowError

Tags: android, stack-overflow

In my Android app, I use a ConcurrentHashMap. Just a get operation，then stack over flow。

Device model: NX511J
Android OS: 5.1.1
Android SDK: 22

Here is the full stack trace：

```
java.lang.StackOverflowError: stack size 1036KB

(13000 same stack trace)

  at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap$ForwardingNode.find(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1507)
    at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap$ForwardingNode.find(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1515)
    at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap$ForwardingNode.find(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1515)
    at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap$ForwardingNode.find(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1515)
    at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap$ForwardingNode.find(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1515)
    at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap$ForwardingNode.find(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1515)
    at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap$ForwardingNode.find(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1515)
    at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap$ForwardingNode.find(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1515)
    at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap$ForwardingNode.find(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1515)
    at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap$ForwardingNode.find(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1515)
    at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap$ForwardingNode.find(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1515)
    at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap$ForwardingNode.find(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1515)
    at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap$ForwardingNode.find(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1515)
    at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap$ForwardingNode.find(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1515)
    at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap$ForwardingNode.find(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1515)
    at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap$ForwardingNode.find(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1515)
    at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.get(ConcurrentHashMap.java:754)
    at com.tmall.wireless.minsk.internal.store.impl.ConfigStoreImpl.c(ConfigStoreImpl.java:526)
    at com.tmall.wireless.minsk.internal.store.impl.ConfigStoreImpl.a(ConfigStoreImpl.java:461)
    at mwo.a(MinskImpl.java:265)
    at jfd.a(TMConfigCenterManager.java:186)
    at ogf.c(TMRewriteEngine.java:177)
    at ogf$1.run(TMRewriteEngine.java:141)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Source code (I think it is not using problem)：

```
private final ConcurrentMap<String, Module> immutableLocalCache = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
    private Module getFromLocal(String moduleName) {
        Module module = immutableLocalCache.get(moduleName);// Stack over flow
        if (null != module) {
            return module;
        }
        //...
        try {
            Module ret = MinskDataConvertUtils.createMinskModule(data);
            immutableLocalCache.put(ret.name, ret);
            return ret;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LogUtils.exception(e);
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you post your code, and some context as well? It's difficult to say what happened just from the stack trace.

Comment: @pablochan android 5.1.1 ，just a simple get invoke, nothing different

Comment: How many entries do you have in that map?

Comment: About 210 keys in the map.

Comment: I updated the source code.

Comment: When do you call getFromLocal method

Comment: I update the full stack trace log.

Answer (score 0):

The common cause for a stack overflow is a bad recursive call or condition you've passed in loop. Typically, this is caused when your recursive functions doesn't have the correct termination condition, so it ends up calling itself forever.

May be you're iterating or using recursion for getting operations. If you're using loop check the condition which you've given. 
Still the error is persist then post your the code.

Comment: actually no recursion invoke

Comment: where you called getFromLocal method

Comment: com.tmall.wireless.minsk.internal.store.impl.ConfigStoreImpl.c(ConfigStoreImpl.java:526)  this line.

Comment: It is hard to guess from stack trace, can you post calling method code